# Function pointer to interface class function in child class constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, interface

I'm working on a project using interface based programming.  The first part of this is for context just in case someone says I'm doing something completely wrong or has a different approach that fixes my issue.

I have a container class that includes several abstract interface classes.  These define functions that return data I need.

This container class has a vector of parts that do not know about the container class, and therefore does not include the interface headers.

Every part is an object of the same type.  When creating these objects, it passes a function pointer as an argument to the constructor of the child objects.  This argument is a pointer to a function defined in one of the interface classes.

I'm trying to pass a pointer using `&iTheInterfaceClass::theDataFunction` to a constructor expecting `U16(*pDataFunction)()`.

This results in the error
`cannot convert 'U16 (iTheInterfaceClass::*)() {aka short unsigned int (iTheInterfaceClass::*)()}' to 'U16 (*)() {aka short unsigned int (*)()}' in initialization`

If the parts include the .h file, I can get this to work, as I just match the prototype to include the namespace in the constructor.  However, this breaks my abstraction.  If each part includes a different interface, I have to create individual classes for each, even though the functionality is identical.

Is there anyway to get the prototypes to match without completely readjusting my strategy here?

Comment: You will need to make `theDataFunction` static. But using function pointers with objects "smells bad".

Comment: You're out of luck. A member function needs an additional parameter for `this`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson If the only thing that differs between objects is the function call (the location of data) in a shared interface, why, specifically, does this "smell bad"?

Comment: Because that's exactly what virtual functions are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said yourself, your constructor expects the following type (excluding names):

```
U16 (*)()
```

However, you are trying to pass the following type:

```
U16 ( iTheInterfaceClass::* )()
```

Your constructor accepts free functions and class functions that are static, but you are trying to pass a non-static member function.They are not of the same type.

You could provide an overload for your constructor that takes in a member function as well as a reference or pointer to the object that the member function will be called on.

It could look something like:

```
public:
    typedef U16( iTheInterfaceClass::*MemberFunctionPtr )(); 

    MyContainer( iTheInterfaceClass& member, MemberFunctionPtr function ) : ... { ... }
```

Assuming you stored that information in some variables somewhere in the class, you could then call that function like so:

```
( member.*function )();
```

Where **member** is the variable that holds a reference to the object that you want to call the function on and **function** is the variable which holds the pointer to said member function.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.  As it turns out, I've redesigned the system to avoid this problem entirely.  This was a dead end solution.